# Ready to use implementation for employee rostering

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

I'm a resident doctor and I stumbled upon the OptaPlanner documentation.
It would be very useful to have a ready to use app which would facilitate rostering for multiple people in the various services my department is managing. I found OptaWeb but didn't find much information on how to host the app or customise it; it seems more of a demo from what I've seen.

Our structure is based on some services being managed by the same people for a few months during the morning shift, plus an afternoon and weekend shift which can be assigned to almost anyone.
We also track total amount of hours worked per week, month and year.

Is there any (free) software which would fit our requirements?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many implementations of such software on top of OptaPlanner, including [Axians MyStaff](https://healthcare.axians.be/mystaff/oncall/) and [Equina](https://www.equinascheduling.com/) (both Red Hat partners IIRC).